# How to add right to left animation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in javascript. I am trying to add animation in my code. Something like, when I mouse hover on a section the ABC should appear and move from right to left and when I remove the mouse from the section it should disappear.
I have implemented the appear disappear part but how to add the animation? Please share with me if anyone has any idea.

My codes are below:

```
<head>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=hide_fostering;
function show_fostering()
{
document.getElementById('fostering').style.visibility="visible";
}

function hide_fostering()
{
document.getElementById('fostering').style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
</head>

<html>    
<body>
<section  onMouseOver="show_fostering()" onMouseOut="hide_fostering()">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">                   
            <div class="col-sm-6">                        
                <h1><strong>CONNECTING</strong></h1>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row pad-top4" id="fostering">                
                    <h3>ABC</h3>                
            </div>                
       </div>
   </div> 
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Given you have the "jquery" tag on your question, have you looked at the [`.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Comment: thank u for the answer, but can u please tell me where to add this .animated() function. I am very new in this.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp). It has a simple tutorial on how to animate using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JavaScript animation library such as TweenJs, alternatively use the jquery `animate()` method.

```
$('#selector').on('click', function(){
 $('div').animate({
  height : 500px;
 });
});
```

This will animate all `div`s when `#selector` will be clicked.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp for a tutorial on jquery`animate()` method.

To do this on mouse hover, use this :

```
$('div').on('mouseover', function(){
 $(this).animate({
  height : 500px;
 });
});
```

This will animate the div which is being hovered on by mouse.

> Jquery `animate()` method is used to animate any CSS animation. So you can animate any CSS property. If you want to animate other properties of CSS, then just replace `height : 500px` with those CSS rules.

For your purpose, use this :

(I have written for visibility part as well, because the code written by you will not work properly. It will check whether your mouse pointer is on top of #fostering, immediately when the page loads. So delete that part.)

```
$('#fostering').on('mouseover', function(){
 $(this).animate({
  visibility : "visible",
  left : "500px"
 });
});

$('#fostering').on('mouseout', function(){
 $(this).animate({
   visibility : "hidden",
   left : "-=500px"
 });
});
```

> You will have to change the value of position property of CSS in order to animate left property in the above code, otherwise it won't work. To do this, use the following CSS :

```
#fostering {
position : relative;
}
```

Comment: where to put this animated() in my code. I am very new in this. Can you please suggest anything.

Comment: I want this on mouse hover. is it possible mouse hover instead of click event?

Comment: @PriyankDey If this worked for you then please accept this as the best answer for your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It will help others too. But my problem is little different. As I mentioned that mouse hover on section (means any part of area under <section> ) the ABC part should be animated. I have written my code. Please add your code on it if it is possible.

Comment: Question says "javascript"

Comment: @SudhirKaushik And it is also tagged "jquery". smh

Comment: and code is JavaScript